# Can I create a delegate in a class that will be passed into the constructor but not make it public?

Tags: c#, generics, delegates

I have a class like so.

```
public class Step<T>
{
    public delegate void Act<T>();

    Act<T> _act;

    public Step(Act<T> action)
    {
        Contract.Requires(action != null);

        _act = action;
    }

    public void PerformStep()
    {
        _act.Invoke();
    }
}
```

My problem is as follows. I want the constructor of this class to be able to accept a delegate with the definition you see in the class. What I do not want is for that delegate to be a public member of my class. The alternative of this is to have a public delegate outside of the class but no other class but this one will need it. Is there a way I can make the delegate private?

If that solution is not possible is there an alternative? This step class is just a wrapper for delegates that are to be run sequentially. There is no need for a signature if I can have a more generic solution.

EDIT: More info for clarification.

The aim of this class it to be able to allow the user to do something like the following.

If I have a Class Car. This car will have methods like Drive, Stop, Turn etc. Using this Step Class the user of the Class should be able to create an instance of their class then do the following.

```
Car c = new Car();
Step<Car> step1 = new Step<Car>(c.TurnLeft);
Step<Car> step2 = new Step<Car>(c.Drive);
Step<Car> step3 = new Step<Car>(c.TurnRight);
//add steps to a collection
c.AddNewRoutine(collection of steps);
c.RunRoutine(identify which routine);
```

The steps will be added to a data structure that will allow them to be executed in order. The car class will contain a data structure that can hold these groups of steps. This then allows any class to be created and have the user set up steps for that class to take, without the class or main program having to hardcode the behaviour.

To finish. I need the step class to be as it is. I just do not want to allow public access to that delegate in any form as the only class who needs it is the Step class.

Comment: Why dont you use built-in Action<T> instead of defining new delegate?

Comment: @Cuong Le, Unless I am mistaken if I used Action<T> I would have to accept at least one parameter in my methods that use the signature?

Comment: Why is the delegate `Act<T>` generic when it accepts no arguments and returns no value?

Comment: I don't see you need <T> as input parameter, so why you have to use <T> in here? If not, use built-in `Action`

Comment: There is a version of `System.Action` that does not take any parameters. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.action.aspx

Comment: I have tried to use action but I am being prompted to pass in 'T obj' to my method call now. How can I call an action with no parameters required?

Comment: Make sure you use the non-generic `Action` (no type parameters) instead of the generic `Action<T>`.

Comment: `Step step3 = new Step(c.TurnRight);` your code will not compile because the compiler has no way of determining the type parameter of the `Step<>` class.

Comment: @HighCore I amended my code when I saw what I was missing. You are correct. I will accept the answer you have proposed below if you change it to recommend I use `Action` instead of telling me to use `Action<T>`

Comment: @Kazuo the problem with that is that if you change the `Action<T>` to a simple `Action` then it makes no sense for the whole `Step` class to be generic. You would also have to remove the `<T>` from the `public class Step`.

Comment: Also, I think there's a little misconception in your approach. If you intend to create a list of steps, these should be `Action<T>`, and accept an instance of `T` as their parameter. Otherwise, you would end up with a list of actions that point to the methods in a specific instance, and these would not be reusable for another instance of say, Car

Comment: @HighCore You are correct. I realised that from another comment. I have since taken all the `<T>` out of my code and everything runs fine. Today is the first time I have started to use generics/delegates/actions/func etc. I clearly have a lot of misconceptions.
Well, my code works fine now that I have removed all the `<T>` even without using `Action`. But, as the code looks right now in my question your solution will not work as Action demands I pass in a parameter. With the delegate the code does not force me to pass anything in even though it has <T> at the end.

Comment: @HighCore The steps are only meant for a specific instance of a class. When a step has been created it is not to be reused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the delegate alltogether and use an Action:

```
private Action<T> _action;

public Step(Action<T> action)
{
   _action = action;
}
```

**Edit:**

you can also have a simple `System.Action` with no type parameters

```
private Action _action;

public Step(Action action)
{
   _action = action;
}
```

**However**, keep in mind that when doing this:

```
var c = new Car();
var step1 = new Step(c.TurnLeft);
```

your're tying the step1 to the actual instance `c`, you will not be able to reuse that step for another instance:

```
var c2 = new Car(); //There's no way to call step1 on this =(
```

Comment: Note that `Act<T>` has no **parameters**, unlike `Action<T>`

Comment: @Greg you're right, then he should use just a regular `Action` (with no type parameters)

Comment: @Greg `Action<T>` doesn't have a return value either.  I think you mean `Act<T>` doesn't have any parameters, unlike `Action<T>`

Comment: @Greg you're right, however, I think the whole purpose of the Step class in the question is to be able to execute actions on some objects, therefore he should find a way to have an `Action<T>` and call it with some parameters

Comment: I have added some info the question to help you understand the purpose of the class.

Comment: @HighCore your solution works if I use Action and not Action<T>. If you could amend your answer to the correct one I will be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 2):

If other classes need to use the delegate then you need to make it public. Period.

Your only real option is to add a constructor that accepts some other kind of paramter(s) that the constructor can then turn into that delegate type.

Comment: No other class needs access to the delegate. Just the class in the question

Comment: But you just said the constructor accepts the delegate as a parameter. How can other classes create an instance of this class if they can't call the constructor?

Comment: They can create an instance of the class using the constructor and all they must do is pass in a method matching the signature of the delegate. They do not need access to the delegate itself in my class.

Comment: If they need to pass in an argument of type `X` then you'll need to expose type `X` to them. There's no getting around that. Hopefully you're not confusing exposing the type of `X` to them and exposing the instance of `X` to them. The delegate definition is just the type. You can still encapsulate the passed-in value of that type.

Comment: The type they are passing in is themselves as shown in the question.
Car c = new Car();
Step<Car> step1 = new Step<Car>(c.TurnLeft);

They do not need to have access to the delegate in my example.

Answer (score 2):

Your example uses a custom delegate that takes no parameters and has no return value. For this the `System.Action` may be ideal. If your custom delegate needs to supply a return value, use `System.Func` instead.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.action.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534960.aspx

From the sample you provided it looks like what you want is something more like this:

```
public class Step<T>
{
    Action _action;

    public Step(Action action)
    {
        Contract.Requires(action != null);

        _action = action;
    }

    public void PerformStep()
    {
        _action.Invoke();
    }
}
```